# Sql- select statement

Tags: sql

When im executing a command like

```
select last_name 
from table 
where last_name in('%a%e%','%e%a%') ;
```

to retrieve all those rows where the last name has an a and an e in it, I'm not getting the result

Comment: If you are using `IN` clause, you can't use pattern matching. You have to change your sql to use `LIKE` statement and join them with logical operator.

Comment: depends what flavour of SQL you are using , but with MySQL I think you need "LIKE" not "IN" with that kind of query.

Comment: As @Lemur mentions:  `where last_name LIKE '%a%e%' OR last_name LIKE '%e%a%'` **EDIT:** juergen d posted a nice solution that doesn't require each condition to be as inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

The `in()` clause does not support wildcards. Use `like`. Then you can simplify that to:

```
select last_name 
from your_table 
where last_name like '%a%'
  and last_name like '%e%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use LIKE statement when using wildcards

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM table 
WHERE last_name LIKE '%a%e%' OR last_name LIKE '%e%a%'
```

When you use `IN` it doesn't do wildcard expansion and searches for exact string you put there. In your case for strings `'%a%e%'` and `'%e%a%'` and not for strings where `a` and `e` are present.

Answer (score 0):

you should use like  not in

```
  select last_name 
  from table 
  where last_name like '%a%e%'
  or last_name like '%e%a%'  ;
```